# Populating a master sheet google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

- I am struggling! Is there a way to fill out information on a Template and then push a button to send the data to a row on the "Master" sheet ?? Without adding a new sheet on the bottom each time it gets populated, the data on the template doesn’t need to be as detailed in the master

On Google sheets

I’m new to this, I know I need to write a code but I can’t find one and don’t have the time to study coding before the deadline needs completing.

Comment: You can use a rangeList to get all of the values and appendRow or put them in a 2d array and use setValues();  Ther are numerous examples of that on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Simple form with answers in rows in Master List

```
function saveFormData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
  const msh = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
  const rgl = sh.getRangeList(["B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6"]);
  const r = rgl.getRanges().map(r => r.getValue());
  msh.getRange(msh.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,r.length).setValues([r]);
}
```

Form:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Question1 | Answer1 |
| 2 | Question2 | Answer2 |
| 3 | Question3 | Answer3 |
| 4 | Question4 | Answer4 |
| 5 | Question5 | Answer5 |
| 6 | Question6 | Answer6 |